# HQL vs. SQL / Hibernate netbeans HQL editor

Tags: sql, hibernate, web-applications, netbeans, hql

I am teaching my self hibernate, and am quite confused of why i can not just write simple SQL queries.

I find it rather more confusing to use than plain SQL (what I am used to)

PLUS: The NetBeans HQL editor I found pretty annoying, It is harder for me to produce a right query in HQL, then in SQL, and why does the shown SQL differ from actual SQL statements ?

So why use it ? - As it is known that hibernate is very resource extensive, and I believe that hibernate is the reason for our app to running out of memory very often, as during the process of redeploying e.g...

I am very interested in knowing why I should use Hibernate and not plain SQL (mysql) statements !?

And maybe a good link for hibernate queries would be nice ;), I am using this one atm:

- http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html

But also interested in any good link explaining the setup of the queries, the mapping, underlying construction etc..

Best Regards
Alex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HQL is object oriented and it's done with the purpose of working on the Java objects representing your DB tables.
A basic advantage is that you can put placeholders like `:orderNumber` (using the colon simbol) in the HQL query and replace with the value of a variable. For example:

```
int orderNumber = 685412;
List<Order> l= 
    session.createQuery("from Order where orderNumber = :orderNumber")
    .setParameter("orderNumber",orderNumber).list();
```

In this way you can modify `orderNumber` in a simple way, evoiding the classical

```
String query = "select * from Order where orderNumber = " + orderNumber + "...";
```

Morover using MySQL syntax would sometimes turn your code not reusable if you migrate your DB to another DBMS.
Anyway I'm still not so convinced about the preference on HQL.

[Here](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbuf.html) you can find the full grammar definition.

Comment: thank you for that.   -   Just another question, so each .hbm.xml file has a according java file, that just needs to have the same name right !?  -  and if I want to write a query, that involves up to three tables, do I have to write that link in each query or can I write a java function or similar to do that for each query, such as a helper.java file !?

Comment: maybe someone is able to tell me more about the setup of the files, as i am trying to understand an existing web application (cyclos) which is very comprehensive. Now they include so many java files to handle db access, that i find it hard to follow the flow. What would you use exampleDao.java files e.g. ??

Comment: - "each .hbm.xml file has a according java file, that just needs to have the same name" -> Yes; maybe it's not necessary the same name (I'm not sure), but it's strongly recommended. In hibernate.cfg.xml you have to put the mapping entries, like this   <mapping resource="Order.hbm.xml"/>

Comment: - "if I want to write a query, that involves up to three tables, do I have to write that link in each query" -> Which link? I don't understand.

- "performance" -> I think that to avoid low performance you have to make precise queries, because intead Hibernate retrieves in cascade all datas in other tables linked by foreign keys.

Comment: i kind of ment if I have to write the table joins in each query i write in hibernate, or If it is possible / handy to write a java function for that !?   - and thanks to you 2 for those msgs / answers

Comment: @Alexander I can't focus on this issue, sorry. Maybe you could ask about it in a new question.

Comment: this is not advantage over plain sql using java jdbc with plain sql you can do it as well.