# Creating inner query in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

how to add a set parameter() metheod inside the inner query in hibernate?

I have try to do like this but already have a errors

this is my code

```
Query query=session.createQuery("select eq.euipmentName,eq.type from Euipment eq where eq.id in(select euipment from Quotation qt where qt. supQuotation=:ids)");          
query.setParameter("ids",id);
list = (List<Euipment>)query.list();
```

Comment: my error is "-----Hibernate: select eq.euipmentName,eq.type from Euipment eq where eq. id in(select euipment from Quotation qt where qt. supQuotation=?)
Unknown column 'qt.supQuotation' in 'where clause'  ---- "

Comment: my error is --Hibernate: select eq.euipmentName,eq.type from Euipment eq where eq. id in(select euipment from Quotation qt where qt. supQuotation=?)
Unknown column 'qt.supQuotation' in 'where clause'--

Comment: Test your query on your database console....Then try using Hibernate

Answer (score 5):

I've done some corrections about your query:
1. qt. supQuotation has a space, I've removed
2. euipment in you sub query haven't alias, I add qt

```
String hql = 
    "select eq.euipmentName,eq.type " +
    " from Euipment eq " +
    " where eq.id in (select qt.euipment from Quotation qt where qt.supQuotation = :ids)";

Query query = session.createQuery(hql);          
query.setParameter("ids",id);
list = (List<Euipment>)query.list();
```

Tell me, if it's OK

If not OK, please post here the error, and check if you have put in hibernate mappping file your classes

Answer (score 1):

From [Hibernate Documentation:](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html)

> Execution of native SQL queries is controlled via the SQLQuery
>   interface, which is obtained by calling Session.createSQLQuery().

- `createQuery()` creates Query object using the HQL syntax.
- `createSQLQuery()` creates Query object using the native SQL syntax.

**So replace `createQuery` with `createSQLQuery` for native SQL query.**

Comment: What gives the query away as being SQL rather than HQL ?

Comment: Dear sir I tried, but also have a exception, I dont know how to use a quotation and parentheses, is it rihgt?

Comment: @Stewart: Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162838/hql-vs-sql-hibernate-netbeans-hql-editor

Comment: @tharaka: Please update your question with exception you are getting.

Comment: @tharaka: Have you tested your query with DB Console?.

Comment: I see nothing in the OP's query that means it can only be SQL - it looks valid HQL to me, and the OP didn't specify, so I was wondering if I missed something? The link you gave doesn't answer it.

Answer (score 0):

Try with Criteria

```
Criteria c = getSession().createCriteria(Euipment.class, "e"); 
c.createAlias("e.quotation", "q"); // inner join by default 
c.add(Restrictions.eq("q.supQuotation", id));       
list = (List<Euipment>)c.list();
```