# hibernate load related records with one sql query

Tags: sql, hibernate, associations

I have a table with multiple columns and in my batch application I need to aggregate on these columns.

For example,

Person

---

Name

Age

Zip

Load all Person(s) with Name "Steve", and for each Person(s) load all Person(s) with Age equals to THIS Person named Steve, and load all Person(s) with Zip equals to THIS Person Named Steve.

So If I was doing a multiple queries it will look like

```
List persons = selectFromPersonsByName("Steve");
For-each (person in persons){
   List personMatchingAge = selectFromPersonByAge(person.getAge());
   List personMatchingZip = selectFromPersonByZip(person.getZip());
   // Do some complex calculations with person and personMatchingAge and personMatchingZip
}
```

**Question**
Using hibernate how can I do this in a single query so I save database round trips and query looks elegant.

Answer (score 0):

It's going to require at least one inner query, I'd focus on writing the query natively and then, if it's actually possible, create a Hibernate named query based on the native query, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18380437/creating-inner-query-in-hibernate).

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Let me try that. I was talking to my colleague and he pointed out that it is a short coming in hibernate and iBatis was a better tool to do this kind of work. Lets see if I can make it work in hibernate though.